# Check if the Cells of a Column Begin With a Specific String [Pandas]

Tags: python, pandas

First of all, thanks for taking the time of reading this.

I have imported the data from a csv into a table in Pandas.
What I want to do is to create a new column and fill it with different numbers that will depend on the string inside of another column.

So if the first column is something like:

```
Column1
Horse1
Horse2
Chicken3
Chiken4
Chicken5
Cow6
Horse7
Cow8
Cow9
```

I want to make a new column, so it will just consider the name of the animal of the first one and give a number to it:

```
Column1               Column2
Horse1                1
Horse2                1
Chicken3              2
Chiken4               2
Chicken5              2
Cow6                  3
Horse7                1
Cow8                  3
Cow9                  3
```

At the moment, what I've tried is (I also leave the comments for you to see what I previously tried and didn't work either):

```
def f(row):
    #if StringMethods.startswith('Horse', na=False):
    #if animals['Column1'].str.contains("Horse")==True:
    #if animals[animals['Column1'].str.contains('Horse', na=False)]:
    if (animals[animals['Horse'].isin(animals['Column1'])]):
        val = 1
    return val

animals['Column2'] = animals.apply(f, axis = 1)
```

And I'm getting this error:

> KeyError: ('Horse', u'occurred at index 0')

What do you think?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
In [34]: mapping = {
   ....:   'Horse': 1,
   ....:   'Chicken': 2,
   ....:   'Cow': 3,
   ....:   'Dog': 4,
   ....: }

In [40]: df['Column2'] = df.Column1.str.replace(r'\d+', '').map(mapping)

In [41]: df
Out[41]:
    Column1  Column2
0    Horse1        1
1    Horse2        1
2  Chicken3        2
3  Chicken4        2
4  Chicken5        2
5      Cow6        3
6    Horse7        1
7      Cow8        3
8      Cow9        3
```